# How to draw the vectors curl meter for electric field lines where magnetic field is constant and are they physically possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image]

How do I draw the curl meter on the electric field lines, I know none of them are physically possible, but do these violate faraday's or grass law?
I think an and d violate faraday and b and c violate guass because of the formulas  - [image]

Comment: "do these violate faraday's or grass law?" You haven't provided enough information. You need the other side of the equations, namely $\rho$ and $\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial t$. Otherwise all of them are plausible electric fields.